# Android, app crashes using Card Flip animation

Tags: android, animation

I seem to be having trouble going through the Card Flip tutorial from the Android dev website. I'm following along and modifying it to suite my needs but it crashes and I'm not sure why. Eclipse doesn't give me any errors in my java code. Was wondering if anyone has any suggestions I can try. I have included the java and logcat. Thanks for your time.

Java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not we're showing the back of the card (otherwise showing the front).
     */
    private boolean mShowingBack = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new CardFrontFragment())
            .commit();
        }else {
            mShowingBack = (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0);
        }

            /**
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
                    */
    }

    private void flipCard() {
        if (mShowingBack) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return;
        }

        // Flip to the back.

        mShowingBack = true;

        // Create and commit a new fragment transaction that adds the fragment for the back of
        // the card, uses custom animations, and is part of the fragment manager's back stack.

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()

                // Replace the default fragment animations with animator resources representing
                // rotations when switching to the back of the card, as well as animator
                // resources representing rotations when flipping back to the front (e.g. when
                // the system Back button is pressed).
                .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                        R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)

                // Replace any fragments currently in the container view with a fragment
                // representing the next page (indicated by the just-incremented currentPage
                // variable).
                .replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment())

                // Add this transaction to the back stack, allowing users to press Back
                // to get to the front of the card.
                .addToBackStack(null)

                // Commit the transaction.
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.card_flip) {
            flipCard();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment representing the front of the card.
     */
    public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A fragment representing the back of the card.
     */
    public static class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_back, container, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
04-09 01:44:56.440: D/dalvikvm(799): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-09 01:45:01.850: D/dalvikvm(799): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 8% free 2905K/3124K, paused 37ms, total 41ms
04-09 01:45:01.850: I/dalvikvm-heap(799): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.892MB for 6220816-byte allocation
04-09 01:45:01.900: D/dalvikvm(799): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 8976K/9200K, paused 43ms, total 43ms
04-09 01:45:02.530: D/(799): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb89a8468, tid 799
04-09 01:45:02.660: W/EGL_emulation(799): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:45:02.670: D/OpenGLRenderer(799): Enabling debug mode 0
04-09 01:45:06.140: W/EGL_emulation(799): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:45:10.960: W/EGL_emulation(799): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:45:13.390: W/EGL_emulation(799): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:46:59.588: D/dalvikvm(1088): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 7% free 2905K/3120K, paused 36ms, total 38ms
04-09 01:46:59.588: I/dalvikvm-heap(1088): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.892MB for 6220816-byte allocation
04-09 01:46:59.638: D/dalvikvm(1088): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 8976K/9196K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
04-09 01:47:00.298: D/(1088): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8acdf90, tid 1088
04-09 01:47:00.458: W/EGL_emulation(1088): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:47:00.478: D/OpenGLRenderer(1088): Enabling debug mode 0
04-09 01:47:03.968: W/EGL_emulation(1088): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:47:08.418: W/EGL_emulation(1088): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:48:39.118: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 8% free 2905K/3124K, paused 41ms, total 45ms
04-09 01:48:39.118: I/dalvikvm-heap(1145): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.892MB for 6220816-byte allocation
04-09 01:48:39.158: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 8976K/9200K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
04-09 01:48:39.728: D/(1145): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8acdfa0, tid 1145
04-09 01:48:39.858: W/EGL_emulation(1145): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:48:39.888: D/OpenGLRenderer(1145): Enabling debug mode 0
04-09 01:48:45.628: W/EGL_emulation(1145): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 01:48:46.758: D/AndroidRuntime(1145): Shutting down VM
04-09 01:48:46.758: W/dalvikvm(1145): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a87ba8)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): Process: you.ca.mohawk.lab6b, PID: 1145
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:124)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:114)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:91)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:72)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:776)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1011)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1212)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:639)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-09 01:48:46.778: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator`

Answer (score 0):

You getting a run time exception, because you have not initialized the `Animation objectAnimator`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your android version becuse it is work only  on 3.0 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this has been resolved by now but I just had the same problem and suggestions did not work for me. What did work (after comparing [google's sample card flip code](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html#animate) with mine) was that using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` was the source of my problem. Changing it to `import android.app.Fragment;` got rid of that error for me. However, this change will affect which versions the app works for.